# Jenkins IOS building and Git branches

Tags: ios, github, jenkins

Hello i am trying to setup Jenkins to build my git hub rep, i have more than one branch, master and develop branch, they have the same code on it at the moment, and when i build my master branch and set up the archive the artifacts to **/*.ipa it builds and saves it just fine. I test my app and it works fine, but when i change my build branch to develop i get a error 
ERROR: ‘***/.ipa’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*.ipa’
to add i been working with this a few days so i am new with Jenkins, and if i did not explain this good , please say so i will try to give more details if needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the pattern you typed does not match any file in the Jenkins workspace. Reason for this could be that either you typed the pattern wrong (which is unlikely if it already worked) or maybe the workspace is currently empty. Try to trigger a build and see if it produces the file you want and archives it.